# Slicing Data from two columns and outputting a new values in Pandas Advice

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Lets assume we have the following Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('subjects.csv')
Col A,              Interest, Col Start, Col Go, Col Learn,
Learn English Lit           
Go Mathematics      
Start Science       
Learn Science       
Go English          
Start Math          
Learn Math          
Go Biology          
Start English
```

I've written some code to pull out interests from a similar dataset as follows

```
#Map Interests 
Mapper = ['English', 'Math', 'Maths', 'Mathematics', 'Biology', 'Science'] 
#Join Mapper to Interest Column
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in Mapper)
df['interest'] = df['col A'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)


#Align Interest Names by creating a dict and replacing values
enter code here
d = {'English Lit' : 'English', 'Biology' : 'Science', 'Mathematics' : 'Maths'} 
df['Interests'] = df['Interests'].replace(d, inplace=False)

>>> Output:

Col A,              Interest, Col Start, Col Go, Col Learn,
    Learn English Lit   English         
    Go Mathematics      Maths
    Start Science       Science
    Learn Science       Science
    Go English          English
    Start Math          Maths
    Learn Math          Maths
    Go Biology          Science
    Start English       English
```

Now I need to measure engagement of Col A with a keyword and interest.

I've done this as follows but I'm sure there are better ways to do this.

```
df['Col Start'][df['col A'].str.contains("Learn", na=False) & df['interest'].str.contains("Science")] = 'Learn'
```

Additionally, what would be the best way to append multiple values into one column? for example if I had:

```
Col A                         
Learn Science, Math, Biology.
```

I would like to have the keyword + interest mapped into a new column with the values separated by commas. This is where my current scripts falls apart, it writes over new values with previous ones, where I was trying to capture all engagement levels (if that makes sense..)

```
Col A                         Col B
Learn Science, Math, Biology. Learn S, Learn, M, Learn B
```

Any help would be appreciative. (please be gentle I started coding in Feb!)

Edit For Clarity:

```
df.loc[df['col A'].str.contains("Learn", na=False) & df['interest'].str.contains("Science"), 'Col Start'] = 'Learn S'
df.loc[df['col A'].str.contains("Learn", na=False) & df['interest'].str.contains("English"), 'Col Start'] = 'Learn E'
df.loc[df['col A'].str.contains("Learn", na=False) & df['interest'].str.contains("Math"), 'Col Start'] = 'Learn M'


Col A                Col Learn
Learn Science, Math  Learn S, Learn M
Learn Math, English  Learn M, Learn E
Learn Science        Learn S.
```

It's possible within my DF that the Col A & Interest may overlap and have recurring outputs. What I want was to capture them all and not overwrite them but append any new inputs with a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) if need extract all values by list with list comprehention and `join` for append string `Learn`:

```
#better is use loc for set new column
df.loc[df['col A'].str.contains("Learn", na=False) & df['interest'].str.contains("Science"), 'Col Start'] = 'Learn'

df['new'] = df['col A'].str.findall('('+ pat + ')').apply(lambda x: ', '.join(['Learn ' + y for y in x]))
print (df)

                           col A     interest Interests Col Start  \
0              Learn English Lit      English   English       NaN   
1                 Go Mathematics  Mathematics     Maths       NaN   
2                  Start Science      Science   Science       NaN   
3                  Learn Science      Science   Science     Learn   
4                     Go English      English   English       NaN   
5                     Start Math         Math      Math       NaN   
6                     Learn Math         Math      Math       NaN   
7                     Go Biology      Biology   Science       NaN   
8  Learn Science, Math, Biology.      Science   Science     Learn   

                                        new  
0                             Learn English  
1                         Learn Mathematics  
2                             Learn Science  
3                             Learn Science  
4                             Learn English  
5                                Learn Math  
6                                Learn Math  
7                             Learn Biology  
8  Learn Science, Learn Math, Learn Biology
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
                 col A         Col Learn
0  Learn Science, Math  Learn S, Learn M
1  Learn Math, English  Learn M, Learn E
2        Learn Science           Learn S
3              Science               val

#create dictionary for new values by keys
d = {'Science':'S', 'English':'E', 'Math':'M'}
#check if Learn
mask = df['col A'].str.contains("Learn", na=False)
#extract all values by keys of dict, replace values by dicts by lookup and join with Learn
s = (df['col A'].str.findall('('+ '|'.join(d.keys()) + ')')
                .apply(lambda x: ', '.join(['Learn ' + d[y] for y in x])))

df['new'] = np.where(mask, s, df['col A'])
print (df)
                 col A         Col Learn               new
0  Learn Science, Math  Learn S, Learn M  Learn S, Learn M
1  Learn Math, English  Learn M, Learn E  Learn M, Learn E
2        Learn Science           Learn S           Learn S
3              Science               val           Science
```

Comment: Brilliant! thank you so much.

df.loc works much better, final Q. If I ran the line you provided above :

df.loc[df['col A'].str.contains("Learn", na=False) & df['interest'].str.contains("Science"), 'Col Start'] = 'Learn'

Multiple times with different variables, would they replace one another or append it self on an existing values.

Comment: @Datanovice - Can you explain more last sentence?

Comment: you are a legend! seriously, thanks for helping all of us newbies :) I hope I'll be able to do the same in the not-so distant future.

Comment: @Datanovice - You are welcome! Btw, you are really good if start in February :)

Comment: It's because we have a helpful community that I'm able to learn so quickly and well, with support needed when I get stuck! (also coming from a linguist background sort of helps.. :))